# Circular Queue Class implementation __str__ method

Tags: python, queue, stack

For my practice questions, my task is to implement the following `CircularQueue` class in Python. I have finished the implementation but am stuck on the `__str__` method because I don't know how to make it match the expected output.

```
class CircularQueue:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.items = [None] * capacity
        self.max_queue = capacity
        self.front = 0
        self.back = self.max_queue - 1
        self.count = 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if not self.is_full():
            self.back = (self.back + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.items[self.back] = item
            self.count += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            item = self.items[self.front]
            self.front = (self.front + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.count -= 1
            return item

    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.max_queue

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[self.front]
        
    def __str__(self): #my issue is here
        return "Front {} Rear".format(self.items)
```

Test:

```
q = CircularQueue(7)
q.enqueue("abc")
q.enqueue("def")
q.dequeue()
q.enqueue(8)
q.enqueue(9)
q.enqueue(10)
q.enqueue(11)
q.dequeue()
q.enqueue("hello")
q.enqueue("world")
print(q)
```

Expected Output:

```
Queue: Front [8, 9, 10, 11, hello, world] Rear
```

Gotten:

```
Queue: Front [8, 9, 10, 11, 'hello', 'world'] Rear
```

Test:

```
q = CircularQueue(4)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
print(q)
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
print(q)
```

Expected Ouput:

```
Queue: Front [3, 4] Rear
Queue: Front [] Rear
```

Get Output:

```
Front [1, 2, 3, 4] Rear
Front [1, 2, 3, 4] Rear
```

Comment: You need to iterate over the elements in your circular queue starting from the first item in your queue to the end, wrapping around if necessary.

Comment: could you please give me an example of how this works please? I don't think I've read about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add the items in your circular queue to a list.

```py
def __str__(self):
    items = []
    if self.count > 0:
        i = self.front
        if i > self.back:
            # we need to loop around
            items.extend(self.items[i:])
            i = 0
        items.extend(self.items[i:self.back + 1])
    return "Queue: Front [{}] Rear".format(", ".join(str(x) for x in items))
```

Another possible way to do this is to define an iterator on your class.

```py
def __iter__(self):
    if self.count == 0:
        return
    i = self.front
    end = self.back
    if i > end:
        while i < self.max_queue:
            yield self.items[i]
            i += 1
        i = 0
    while i <= self.back:
        yield self.items[i]
        i += 1

def __str__(self):
    return "Queue: Front [{}] Rear".format(", ".join(str(x) for x in self))
```

Comment: But this is not returning a Queue.

Comment: @yowhatsup123 what do you mean? Which part should be returning a Queue?

Comment: This returns `Front [3, 4] Rear` instead of `Queue: Front [3, 4] Rear`

Comment: It's a trivial fix to write `Queue: ` at the front of the string.

Comment: This code is failing for one input, where some of the items are strings, how should I tackle that?

Comment: If you print a list, it will call `repr()` on the items within the list, which is why strings will have the quotes. To get around this, we will need to implement the list printing logic ourselves.

Comment: Does that mean adding an `if..else` statement and saying if `type(item) == str` then do something else do something else? I'm sorry I'm still an amateur so don't know how to do this

Comment: @yowhatsup123, I updated the answer with the list printing logic